# How to access iPhone through USB

Tags: iphone

I plugged my I Phone into the USB port and don’t see the photos or music. I looked in search computer and online sources.

Thanks
John

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I mount my iPhone 6s on Ubuntu 16.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/812006/how-can-i-mount-my-iphone-6s-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 1):

This depends also on the type of iPhone, some details [here](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/iphone) (it's in French, but the images  can be helpful).

Tested with an iPhone 5s.

### To transfer pictures and (camera) videos from iphone to Ubuntu:

- install [**Shotwell**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/lucid/shotwell/);
- open Shotwell, go to *Edit-Preferences* and set the Library location (when started it will import automatically from `~/Pictures`); also, set the directory structure (or it will create its own sub-folders down to month and day by default, could be cumbersome; to only create folders for years, set *Custom-Patern*: `%Y`, for month-year select `%m-%Y`);

[image]

- connect phone by USB, unlock the phone; go to *File-Import from folder*, select the phone; when asked to copy or just import, select 'copy' (otherwise the images from the phone will only be accessed and added to its library (as links) by the program without being copied to your computer);

[image]

after that importing will start, it takes some time;

- at the end you will be asked if you want to ***delete from the iphone the imported pictures*** - be careful there!
- the imported pictures will be remembered as part of the library once copied and will not be imported/copied next time even if you have deleted/moved them from your computer; to copy/import them again, go to *Libray-Missing files*, wait for search, then select the ones that you want to import again, right-click and remove, then restart the whole process to import.

---

(I will try to post on importing audio as soon as possible.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see photos and videos displayed on your computer from your iphone you need itunes. Unfortunately itunes isnt available for linux. You can use Wine to fix this problem. Here is a tutorial http://freshtutorial.com/install-itunes-ubuntu-linux/