# How can I mount my iPhone 6s on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, usb, mount, iphone

I'm new to Ubuntu, and I don't know how to mount my iPhone.

I would like to download iTunes, but I saw that USB doesn't work, but I just need to access to all my files and APP because would like to transfer APP from pc to iPhone.

Comment: Is the phone jailbroken?

Comment: No it is not, fresh as new

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to mount the iPhone's filesystem normally via USB on any OS. Moreover, I don't know of any applications for Ubuntu (or any Linux distro for that matter) that allow the syncing of apps to an iOS device.

Comment: You can try to run Windows in a virtual machine using VirtualBox, and manage apps via iTunes in the VM.

Comment: I read somewhere that it could work installing GKSU NAUTILUS...(honestly, dunno wtf it is), but it gave some error...and cannot download VirtualBox...do you have any link?

Comment: The download for VirtualBox is [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads). The Ubuntu downloads should be at the top.

Comment: I really appreciate your help @fakedad, but I still need you..
----
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Windows XP.

VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

----

Comment: Check out [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/213795/how-to-enable-intel-vt-x-in-your-computers-bios-or-uefi-firmware/) article on how to enable VT-X in your BIOS. If you don't see it there, you can instead just disable using VT-X for the VM by unchecking Ënable VT-x/AMD-V" under the **Acceleration** tab in  the **System** settings in the Settings for the virtual machine.

Answer (score 38):

Evidently I was wrong about being able to mount an iPhone on Ubuntu. You can perform this using the following steps on yakkety. Note, you *would* need the device to be jailbroken in order to load apps onto the device this way, but this method will suffice for getting media from the device.

**Option 1: Using a script**

If you want to save yourself some time, you can download a script [here](http://pastebin.com/6u0TEhjz) to do most of the work of the process for you.

Once downloaded, you will need to change the permisions so you can execute the script. Assuming you downloaded it with the default name, `iphone_setup.sh`, `cd` to the directory in which you downloaded the file and do

```
chmod u+x iphone_setup.sh
```

Convert the Windows line endings by doing

```
ex -bsc '%!awk "{sub(/\r/,\"\")}1"' -cx iphone_setup.sh
```

Then run the script with root privileges using

```
sudo ./iphone_setup.sh
```

This will complete all of **Step 1** of the manual setup for you, as well as **Step 3** and **Step 4**. You will then need to do **Step 2** and **Step 5** of the manual setup after the script finishes running.

**Option 2: Doing it manually**

**Step 1: Installing the tools**

Before plugging in the iPhone, you will need to install the several programs to make it possible to mount the iPhone.

**Step 1.1: Installing several important tools with apt-get**

Do the following in the terminal to install a few packages that will be needed for any version of iOS.

```
sudo apt-get install ideviceinstaller python-imobiledevice libimobiledevice-utils python-plist usbmuxd
```

*If you are connecting an iPhone with an iOS version before iOS 9, you can skip the remaining substeps of step 1 and instead just do the following:*

```
sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice6 libplist3 ifuse
```

**Step 1.2: Installing tools for building**

Use `apt-get` to install a few programs needed to build the programs in the following steps

```
sudo apt-get install libtool autoconf automake
```

**Step 1.3: Installing libplist**

First, install the required dependencies for building `libplist`. In order to do this, do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev python-dev
```

Then download the [latest version](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libplist/archive/master.zip) of `libplist` from GitHub, and extract the contents of the zip file to some directory.  For instance, if you are in the directory where you downloaded the `libplist` zip file, do `unzip libplist-master.zip`.

You should now have a directory called "libplist-master" in the directory to which you extracted the `libplist` zip file. `cd` into this directory from the terminal, and the run

```
./autogen.sh
```

When the `./autogen.sh` script is done running, run

```
make
```

And, finally, run

```
sudo make install
```

**Step 1.4: Installing libusbmuxd**

This step is similar to the previous step, except we are installing `libusbmuxd` instead of `libplist`.

First, download the [latest version](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libusbmuxd/archive/master.zip) of `libusbmuxd` from GitHub. Again, extract the contents to a directory, and `cd` to the directory `libusbmuxd-master`. Then run the following:

```
./autogen.sh
```

When this is finished, run

```
make
```

followed by

```
sudo make install
```

**Step 1.5: Installing libimobiledevice**

First, install the build dependencies by doing the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Then download the [latest version](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/archive/master.zip) of `libimobiledevice` from GitHub. Extract as in the previous two steps; you should get a directory inside the directory to which you extracted called `libimobiledevice-master`. `cd` into this directory, and, again, run

```
./autogen.sh
```

When this is finished, run

```
make
```

followed by

```
sudo make install
```

**Step 1.6: Installing a better version of usbmuxd**

First, uninstall the old version of `usbmuxd` by doing

```
sudo apt-get remove usbmuxd
```

Then, install the build dependencies by doing

```
sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice-dev libplist-dev libusb-dev libusb-1.0.0-dev libtool-bin libtool
```

Then, download the [latest version](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/usbmuxd/archive/master.zip) of `usbmuxd` from GitHub. Extract and `cd` to the `usbmuxd-master` directory. Again, run

```
./autogen.sh
```

When this is finished, run

```
make
```

followed by

```
sudo make install
```

**Step 1.7: Installing ifuse**

This is the last thing you will need to install!

First install, the build dependencies by doing

```
sudo apt-get install libfuse-dev
```

Download the [latest version](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ifuse/archive/master.zip) of `ifuse` from GitHub. Extract it to some directory, and `cd` into the directory `ifuse-master`, and `cd` into that directory.

This time there is an extra step in building the program. Do

```
./autogen.sh
```

as usual, but then do

```
./configure
```

as well. Then, continue on to the normal

```
make
```

and

```
sudo make install
```

**Step 2: Running usbmuxd and attaching iPhone**

This step is simple. Run `usbmuxd` in the terminal, and then plug in the iPhone.

Now check to see if the device was recognized correctly by doing

```
dmesg | grep ipheth
```

If nothing shows up, try disconnecting the iPhone, running `usbmuxd` again, and then plugging back in. Then check again.

**Step 3: Creating a mount point for the iPhone**

You can manually create a mount point for the iPhone by doing

```
sudo mkdir /media/iPhone
```

You will then likely want to change the permissions for the mount point. Do

```
sudo chmod 777 /media/iPhone
```

**Step 4: Editing the ifuse configuration file**

The ifuse  configuration file `/etc/fuse.conf` requires editing if you want to access the iPhone without being root.

Edit the configuration file using your favorite editor, for example gedit

```
sudo gedit /etc/fuse.conf
```

In the file ensure that the following two lines are under the line that says `# Allow non-root users to specify the allow_other or allow_root mount options`:

```
op$
user_allow_other
```

Save the file and quit the editor.

**Step 5: Pairing the iPhone**

Run the following line in order to pair your iPhone using `idevicepair`:

```
idevicepair pair
```

**Step 6: Mounting with ifuse**

Run the following line to mount the device at the mount point specified earlier:

```
ifuse /media/iPhone
```

**NOTE**: At this point you may mount the root filesystem if you have your phone jailbroken by doing the following line instead

```
ifuse /media/iPhone/ --root
```

The iPhone should now be accessible at `/media/iPhone` through your file browser.

When you want to unmount, do the following two lines

```
fusermount -u /media/iPhone/
idevicepair unpair
```

These steps were adapted for xenial from [this tutorial at dedoimedo](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/linux-iphone-6.html), then further modified to suit devices with iOS 9+.

Comment: [ 1461.760447] ipheth 1-2:4.2 enp0s20u2c4i2: renamed from eth0
stream13@stream13-HP-Stream-Notebook-PC-13:~$ mkdir /media/iPhone
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/media/iPhone’: Permission denied

I don't know what to do mate...

Comment: @RizioA.Sorry, that should have been `sudo mkdir /media/iPhone`

Comment: @RizioA.Same with `sudo chmod 777 /media/iPhone`

Comment: This does not work for iOS 10: "GnuTLS error: Error in the pull function. Failed to connect to lockdownd service on the device. Try again. If it still fails try rebooting your device."

Comment: @zgoda I have updated the answer to have instructions for getting this to work for iOS 9+. I tested it twice on fresh installations of Ubuntu, once with an iPhone 6S with iOS 9.3.3, and once with an iPhone 6 with iOS 10.0.2.

Comment: Use [iosTransferGUI](https://github.com/programmin1/iosTransferGUI) to easily transfer files to and from apps. Requires `python2.7`, `python-fuse`, and maybe something else.

Comment: That was a bit lengthy to do (maybe someone has a script), but worth it! Golden post! (and fyi my iPhone is not even jailbroken)

Comment: @ringø A script is a good idea. I've added a bash script which does steps 1, 3, and 4. I'm not very experienced with bash scripting, so it's a bit messy, though. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Step#6 is not working for me, but file explorer worked, thanks a lot

Comment: I already had the latest libplist, libusbmuxd, libimobiledevice, usbmuxd, and ifuse from `apt`. I kept getting the same error zgoda got. After I   edited the `fuse.conf` file, it still gave the error on the command line, but it started working in the file explorer after I unmounted and clicked on `iPhone` again!

Comment: This is back to broken.

Comment: @Chloe I will work later this weekend on creating a fix for the issues people seem to be having with iOS 10. Based on a test I did just a couple of days ago, this is still working with iOS 9.

Comment: @fakedad Perfect, golden. Tested fine with IOS 10.2.1 on an iPhone 6s with Ubuntu 16.04 using the the script and steps  2,5,6   ie. usbmuxd; idevicepair pair; ifuse /media/iPhone.  My iPhone is not jailbroken. I downloaded my photos using dolphin (KDE desktop).

Comment: I used the manual process on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and iPhone 7 on iOS 10.3.3 not jailbroken, worked fantastically well

Comment: @APE I encountered an error at the end of the manual process with iOS 10.3.3 and Ubuntu 16.04LTS `GnuTLS error: Error in pull function.` Did you encounter this? Everything else went very smoothly. It is an iphone 6s.

Comment: @sequoia Nope I didn't get that issue, sorry :( However if you google that message there's plenty of suggestions. Some say it's a network issue, and you can add more logs to investigate. Others mentioned library issues and suggested other things to install. Good luck!

Comment: I followed these instructions on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with an Iphone SE with IOS 11.2.2 and get this error message when attempting step 6, even after rebooting the iphone: `Failed to connect to lockdownd service on the device.
Try again. If it still fails try rebooting your device.`

Comment: @LouisGagnon I have not been able to recreate the problem, but I am using an iPhone 6s with iOS 9.3.3. Unfortunately, I do not have the iPhone I once used to test different versions of iOS, but I may test this out when I have access to it again. I imagine the problem is that `imobiledevice` has not been updated for 11.2.2 (since it is very recent), but I don't know for sure.

Comment: @LouisGagnon Evidently some people have had success with the fix suggested in the community wiki answer and [bytepan's](https://askubuntu.com/users/549895/bytepan) answer (basically an extra step before **Step 5** here). I have never been able to catch this error and verify that the fix works, so I haven't incorporated it into my answer, but it might solve the issue if the problem is that `idevicepair` is using outdated versions of some of the tools built.

Comment: @fakedad I took a while to convince myself to download and compile all these github repositories, but the solution you pointed out did work. Thanks.

Comment: @LouisGagnon What was your concern with downloading and compiling the code from the GitHub repositories?

Comment: @fakedad time was the concern (but I was positively surprised to see that compilation was very straightforward and quick)

Comment: ** As of 2020, this answer seems to be no longer working

Answer (score 8):

Tested on iPhone 4S on 16.04 and now SE on 18.04; no reason to believe it will be different on 6 or later versions

[EDIT: see below it works all the way to iPhone 7].

Fairly simple route:

➊ INSTALL:

```
sudo apt install ideviceinstaller python-imobiledevice libimobiledevice-utils  usbmuxd libimobiledevice6 libplist3 ifuse python3-plist
```

if on a 64-bit install

```
sudo apt install ideviceinstaller python-imobiledevice libimobiledevice-utils  usbmuxd libimobiledevice6 libplist3 ifuse python3-plist:i386
```

if on a 32-bit install

you may need to do this too:
sudo mkdir /var/lib/lockdown
sudo chmod 777 /var/lib/lockdown

➋ in Terminal to see your iphone address:

```
 lsusb -v 2> /dev/null | grep -e "Apple Inc" -A 2
```

You will see something thus:

iManufacturer           1 Apple Inc.
iProduct                2 iPhone
iSerial                 3 ca00d62380d42746b8ff8280....d1fd7b7119ca

➌ Open Nautilus

enter the iSerial from above:

```
afc://ca00d62380d4274....f8280a91ed1fd7b7119ca/
```

NOW you see your files.*Photos are in DCIM folder*

➍ As an embellishment you could install VLC Mobile
from App Store FREE of course which will let you play formats itunes cannot handle Flac Wavpack etc

you will see/place the music files in *Documents on iPhone* next to *iPhone* on left of page [This is on LXDE; must look similar in other Desktop Environments]

=== TIP ===

If iphone VLC files are not visible on your PC; I found this brings them   back:unplug phone run command below then replug

```
sudo usbmuxd --verbose -f
```

Comment: This worked great for accessing my iPhone 7 Plus's photos on 18.04 and is way simpler than the other answers. Thanks!

Comment: Thanx Abe for saying it works on 7 since all I have is a 4S ....    good to know for other folks or if I ever fork out for a more recent toy :]  no need as yet as 4S   still marvelous although from 2011 !

Comment: Now tested it on iPhone SE
and fine there too

Answer (score 3):

It seems that with iOS 10.2 Apple has broken it again.
To fix:

1. Download from GitHub latest versions of: `libplist`, `libusbmuxd`, `libimobiledevice`, `ifuse` and `usbmuxd`
2. Extract ZIP files in a folder that you like, enter in each directory and launch compilation of the corresponding library (if you don't know how to do, just follow instructions inside the readme file inside each lib and remember that the development version of `openssl` is called `libssl-dev` when required). Please note that last command 'sudo make install' should put compiled libraries in `/usr/local/lib`.
3. Make sure that environment vars point to this new versions rather than the old ones included in official packages:

   ```
   sudo LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib usbmuxd    
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
   ```
4. Connected your iOS 10.2 device to your computer:

   ```
   idevicepair pair
   ```
5. Select "Trust" to the warning "Trust This Computer?" on your device:

   ```
   idevicepair pair
   ```
6. Mount the iOS filesystem

   ```
   ifuse Mountpoint_Directory/
   ```

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04 and iPhone 7 with iOS 10.2

Comment: On my stock Ubuntu 16.04 system, the phone doesn't even show up in lsusb.  Would this library set fix that so that I can get iTunes working within VirtualBox?

Comment: Several months have passed and I honestly don't remember perfectly, but I think that my iPhone was detected in lsusb even before applying the new libraries, so I don't know if they can fix the issue you're talking about.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue on Ubuntu 16.04 and I can finally access my photos. One small note: it would be more appropriate to use this command: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib` in the two substeps of n. 3. This way your current LD_LIBRARY_PATH, if any, gets preserved. Thanks again for sharing!

Comment: I continually will get a message when I try to mount with `:~$ ifuse /media/iPhone` saying: `There was an error accessing the mount point: Input/output error` Does anyone else have this problem and is there a solution?

Answer (score 2):

> After having built new versions of libplist, libusbmuxd,
>   libimobiledevice, ifuse and usbmuxd under /usr/local/lib, those
>   versions have to be taken into use when calling the commands to
>   connect the iPhone (instead of using the old library versions, which
>   is done by default). So I did the following in a bash-shell (make sure
>   to unlock (enter your code or use your fingerprint) your iPhone before
>   each action):
>
> ```
> sudo LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib usbmuxd
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
> idevicepair pair
> ifuse /media/iPhone
> ```
>
> <sub>(comment originated from [user639768](https://askubuntu.com/users/639768/user639768) and was posted as a question, but has since been deleted.)</sub>