# libimobiledevice problem

Tags: 16.04

Trying to connect Kubuntu 16.04 box with usb cable connected iPad Pro 12.9 running ios 10.0.2

```
:~$ /usr/bin/idevicepair -u ***** pair
SUCCESS: Paired with device

:~$ idevicepair validate *********
SUCCESS: Validated pairing with device

:~$ ifuse ~/media/ipad -u ******
GnuTLS error: Error in the pull function.
Failed to connect to lockdownd service on the device.
Try again. If it still fails try rebooting your device.
```

Reboot, repeat, same result. Anyone know what's wrong, OR is there a better forum to ask this question?

Thx, Gus

---

Apologies Rinzwind I wasn't trying to troll anyone. Anyway below are results per your suggestions. I'm not sure how to check if openssl is using SSLv3 (help?)

```
$ env | grep 99
GNUTLS_DEBUG_LEVEL=99

$ /usr/bin/idevicepair validate
gnutls[2]: Enabled GnuTLS 3.4.10 logging...
gnutls[2]: Intel SSSE3 was detected
gnutls[2]: Intel AES accelerator was detected
gnutls[2]: Intel GCM accelerator was detected
SUCCESS: Validated pairing with device ***********
```

(below mounting to /media/ipad not ~/media/ipad .....)

```
$ ifuse /media/ipad -u **********
gnutls[2]: Enabled GnuTLS 3.4.10 logging...
gnutls[2]: Intel SSSE3 was detected
gnutls[2]: Intel AES accelerator was detected
gnutls[2]: Intel GCM accelerator was detected
gnutls[5]: REC[0x19d7300]: Allocating epoch #0
gnutls[3]: ASSERT: gnutls_constate.c:596
gnutls[5]: REC[0x19d7300]: Allocating epoch #1
gnutls[4]: HSK[0x19d7300]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_RSA_AES_128_CBC_SHA1 (00.2F)
gnutls[4]: HSK[0x19d7300]: Keeping ciphersuite: GNUTLS_RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA1 (00.35)
gnutls[4]: EXT[0x19d7300]: Sending extension ENCRYPT THEN MAC (0 bytes)
gnutls[4]: EXT[0x19d7300]: Sending extension SAFE RENEGOTIATION (1 bytes)
gnutls[4]: EXT[0x19d7300]: Sending extension SESSION TICKET (0 bytes)
gnutls[4]: HSK[0x19d7300]: CLIENT HELLO was queued [62 bytes]
gnutls[11]: HWRITE: enqueued [CLIENT HELLO] 62. Total 62 bytes.
gnutls[11]: HWRITE FLUSH: 62 bytes in buffer.
gnutls[5]: REC[0x19d7300]: Preparing Packet Handshake(22) with length: 62 and min pad: 0
gnutls[9]: ENC[0x19d7300]: cipher: NULL, MAC: MAC-NULL, Epoch: 0
gnutls[11]: WRITE: enqueued 67 bytes for 0x19dac30. Total 67 bytes.
gnutls[5]: REC[0x19d7300]: Sent Packet[1] Handshake(22) in epoch 0 and length: 67
gnutls[11]: HWRITE: wrote 1 bytes, 0 bytes left.
gnutls[11]: WRITE FLUSH: 67 bytes in buffer.
gnutls[11]: WRITE: wrote 67 bytes, 0 bytes left.
gnutls[3]: ASSERT: gnutls_buffers.c:1154
gnutls[10]: READ: -2 returned from 0x19dac30, errno=0 gerrno=0
gnutls[3]: ASSERT: gnutls_buffers.c:367
gnutls[3]: ASSERT: gnutls_buffers.c:588
gnutls[3]: ASSERT: gnutls_record.c:1038
gnutls[3]: ASSERT: gnutls_record.c:1158
gnutls[3]: ASSERT: gnutls_buffers.c:1409
gnutls[3]: ASSERT: gnutls_handshake.c:1446
gnutls[3]: ASSERT: gnutls_handshake.c:2757
gnutls[5]: REC[0x19d7300]: Start of epoch cleanup
gnutls[5]: REC[0x19d7300]: End of epoch cleanup
gnutls[5]: REC[0x19d7300]: Epoch #0 freed
gnutls[5]: REC[0x19d7300]: Epoch #1 freed
GnuTLS error: Error in the pull function.
Failed to connect to lockdownd service on the device.
Try again. If it still fails try rebooting your device.
```

Comment: "OR is there a better forum to ask this question?" always good to troll the people you want help from :)

Comment: Good luck connecting an iOS device to a Linux computer. Not gonna happen.

Answer (score 4):

Tried following PPA and it works for me ( thanks to [Martin Salbaba](https://launchpad.net/~martin-salbaba) ),
Upgrade to libimobiledevice and relative packages to newer version:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:martin-salbaba/ppa+libimobiledevice
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install libimobiledevice-utils ifuse
```

Steps to pair:

Connected your iOS 10 device to your computer:

```
idevicepair pair
```

Select "Trust" to the Warning "Trust This Computer?" on your device:

```
idevicepair pair
```

Mount the iOS filesystem

```
ifuse Directory_to_mount_iDevice/
```

Above tested on iPhone 6s with iOS 10.1.1

And:
unmount properly:

```
fusemount -u Directory_to_mount_iDevice/
```

Reference:

[How can I mount my iPhone 6s on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/812006/how-can-i-mount-my-iphone-6s-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that with iOS 10.2 Apple has broken it again.
To fix:

1. Download from GitHub latest versions of: *libplist, libusbmuxd, libimobiledevice, ifuse and usbmuxd*
2. Put them in */usr/local/lib* and compile (if you don't know how to do, just follow instructions inside the readme file inside each lib and remember that the development version of *openssl* is called *libssl-dev* when required)
3. Make sure that environment vars point to this new versions rather than the old ones included in official packages:

   ```
   sudo LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib usbmuxd  
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
   ```
4. Connected your iOS 10.2 device to your computer:

   ```
   idevicepair pair
   ```
5. Select "Trust" to the warning "Trust This Computer?" on your device:

   ```
   idevicepair pair
   ```
6. Mount the iOS filesystem

   ```
   ifuse Mountpoint_Directory/
   ```

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04 and iPhone 7 with iOS 10.2

Answer (score 1):

> GnuTLS error: Error in the pull function.

is a network error. You can set [`GNUTLS_DEBUG_LEVEL`](https://gnutls.org/manual/html_node/Debugging-and-auditing.html) to 99 to get more info on the error. It is likely going to tell you you are using older libraries than required or there is something wrong with openssl.

But ...

> ifuse ~/media/ipad -u

seems wrong to me?  Why is there a ~ in front of /media? I would assume you mount a device in /media and not in your home?

Also make sure you do not use openssl without SSLv3 or it will fail with that lockdownd service error notice.

- [This might help too](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/issues/346#issuecomment-246592802).
- [And this](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/issues/294#issuecomment-207890545).