# Mounting IOS 10.1 on Ubuntu 15.04 to retrieve photos

Tags: mount, permissions, 15.04, iphone

I am trying to mount an iPhone 6, running iOS 10.1 on Ubuntu 15.04 in order to retrieve picture data from the phone.  I have already tried techniques that worked on other Ubuntu versions/iOS versions for mounting the device (e.g.- different usb ports, sudo idevicepair unpair && sudo idevicepair pair, updating imobiledevice, using sudo chmod 777 /var/lib/lockdown , etc...).  Nothing seems to work and I keep getting the "unhandled lockdown error" message (different numbers for it).

I have also made sure the iphone was unlocked prior to connecting and trusted the device, but still have the same issue.

Any ideas/suggestions are appreciated from the group.  Thank you

Comment: Sorry, but Ubuntu 15.04 is EOL and thus no longer supported. Please consider upgrading to a current release.

Comment: Have you tried the answer I posted to [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/812006/how-can-i-mount-my-iphone-6s-on-ubuntu-16-04/812379#812379) similar question?