# Mounting iPhone on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mount, 18.04, filesystem, root, iphone

I have been trying to access the root filesystem of my jailbroken iPhone 4 on Ubuntu 18.04. I followed the steps of this: [How can I mount my iPhone 6s on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/812006/how-can-i-mount-my-iphone-6s-on-ubuntu-16-04). Everything went smoothly but I could only access the /private/var/mobile/Media/ folder. My problem is I don't have access to the other folders.
I'm completely new at Linux so maybe I did something wrong, I don't know.
I tried SSH and it works fine but if there is another solution it would be even better.

Comment: Not sure if it will fit your needs but I use a ftp server on the phone

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any solution that works without internet connection?

Comment: If it does not work when you plug it in directly, then no, in my experience installing a ftp server is the way to go. You obviously ha e internet as you are posting here so you can decide what is easier

Comment: Internet is not very stable in the area where I live that's why I'm asking if there is another way.

Comment: Okay I realised instead of this line "ifuse /media/iPhone" I have to use this "ifuse /media/iPhone/ --root" and than it works. It is written in the instructions I linked above I just didn't pay attention.