# How I can Sync Between Iphone 5s and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: iphone

I have Iphone 5s and I want to have access to my photos, videos, music from Ubuntu laptop 16.04 LTS 
I tried these 4 answers which are in this question and it did not work

[How can I mount my iPhone 6s on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/812006/how-can-i-mount-my-iphone-6s-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: none of the answers are working

Comment: Please detail in your question what you have tried and what is not working. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!