# Undoing changes made by running iPhone connection script.

Tags: uninstall, connection, iphone

Okay, let's assume that I am a novice and an idiot and work from there.

In attempting to connect my iPhone to a new Ubuntu installation, I followed the directions described by "fakedad" in his post:

[How can I mount my iPhone 6s on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/812006/how-can-i-mount-my-iphone-6s-on-ubuntu-16-04/812379#812379)

(Here is where the idiocy comes into play.)

I had downloaded the script to my Desktop, and I RAN IT FROM THERE (!?!), putting the various tools and so on right on the Desktop! Naturally, I would rather not have them there but the various directories are locked and I cannot remove them through consigning them to the Trash or Deleting them.

How would I go about un-installing, removing, deleting or otherwise getting these off my desktop so that I may re-install them in a more convenient place, wherever that may be (Suggestions are more than welcome!).

Many thanks in advance,

PDA